# Is this a typo in C++ Primer 5th Edition Section 18.3.4 Virtual Interitance

Tags: c++, class, oop, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

> In practice, the requirement that an intermediate base class specify its inheritance as virtual rarely causes any problems. Ordinarily, a class hierarchy that uses virtual inheritance is designed at one time either by one individual or by a single project design group. It is exceedingly rare for a class to be developed independently that needs a virtual base in one of its base classes and in which the developer of ***the new base class*** cannot change the existing hierarchy.

Did the author mean ***the new derived class*** instead of ***the new base class*** ?

Comment: I think the author is referring to the new *intermediate* base class that they bring up in the first sentence. It is confusing though.

Comment: “the new base class” refers back ro “one of its base classes” a few words back in the same sentence.

Comment: I would also say that he is speculating without evidence.